# How do I find out which wi-fi hardware is on my laptop?

Tags: networking, drivers, .desktop

Since installing Ubuntu (and retiring Windows) on my wife's laptop, the Wi-fi keeps dropping out every 20 min or so. It disconnects and then re-connects.

I'm not sure what to do, but I imagine the first step is to figure out what wi-fi hardware is on the machine and then try alternative drivers. But I'm stuck right on step 1, how do I find out what wifi hardware is installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
```

note that that will also list the cabled interface.